# How to create GROUP BY on min and max date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a database table like this

```
emp_id start-date  end_date    title    location
111    1-JAN-2000  31-DEC-2003 MANAGER  NYO
111    1-JAN-2003  31-DEC-2005 MANAGER  BOM
111    1-JAN-2006  31-DEC-2007 CFO      NYO
111    1-JAN-2008  31-DEC-2015 MANAGER  NYO
```

I have created a SQL code already with GROUP BY  and min , max function

```
select emp_id,min(start_date),max(end_date),title
from table1
group by emp_id,title
```

What is expect is this:

```
111 1-JAN-2000 31-DEC-2005 MANAGER
111 1-JAN-2006 31-DEC-2007 CFO
111 1-JAN-2008 31-DEC-2015 MANAGER
```

What i am getting is:

```
111 1-JAN-2000 31-DEC-2015 MANAGER 
111 1-JAN-2006 31-DEC-2007 CFO
```

Comment: Each row represents a group. Your groups are defined as: emp_id and title. So rows 1 and 3 in your expected are grouped into one... In order to help you, we may need to see sample data from table1.

Comment: So you don't want min and max - you want something that starts a new group whenever there is a change in title value.

Comment: @kbball : I have added the location column

Comment: @DanielM : So can you suggest me a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem with date-chains.  I would suggest using a `left join` to find where the islands start.  Then a cumulative sum and aggregation:

```
select emp_id, title, min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when tprev.emp_id is null then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by t.emp_id, t.title order by t.start_date) as grouping
      from t left join
           t tprev
           on t.emp_id = tprev.emp_id and
              t.title = tprev.title and
              t.start_date = tprev.end_date + 1
     ) t
group by grouping, emp_id, title;
```

Comment: the above code is working as per my intial tests..will integrate with my code and let us all know how it went.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using window function find the gap and make it the group

```
with cte1 as
(
select a.*,
row_number()over(partition by emp_id,title order by start-date) rn,
row_number() over(order by start-date) rn1
from table_name a
) select emp_id,
  min(start-date),
  max(end_date),
  max(title)
  from cte1 group by emp_id, rn1-rn
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fb419f65f81de640a2d9a22f05fefef7)