# Concatenating tablenames and columns in joined SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i use the content of `switches.address` as a table-name, and `switches.pin` as a column-name to perform some sort of joined query on "switches" that that gives me (in the below case) the value of `PIN3` from `0x68`?

something like

```
SELECT name, state FROM switches
```

with `0x68.PIN3` as state

```
CREATE TABLE switches (
name varchar(20), address varchar(20), pin varchar(20));

INSERT INTO switches VALUES
("Lights_Kitchen", "0x68", "PIN3");

|      name      | address | pin  |
+----------------+---------+------+
| Lights_Kitchen |  0x68   | PIN3 |


CREATE TABLE `0x68` (
PIN1 INT, PIN2 INT, PIN3 INT, PIN4 INT);

INSERT INTO `0x68` VALUES 
(0,0,1,0)

| PIN1 | PIN2 | PIN3 | PIN4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|  0   |  0   |  1   |  0   |
```

and so on..

Comment: Hi, Can you please reformat your code. I am unable to understand the problem here. Please add some Table data as demo. You can check some other questions on this portal for example formattings. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011198/how-to-create-group-by-on-min-and-max-date)

Comment: Please describe formal algorithm in terms of tables and fields, not *a value X from table Y*. Why? Because to get the value X from table Y you just need to `select distinct col from Y where col = X`. Other manipulations are attempts to invent the way you need it

Comment: You need to generate dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. Tables and column names can't be generated dynamically in a regular query. It's usually a bad design to require this.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You could just create a table with the address as a column, and your query would then contain a clause like `WHERE address = '0x68'`. You might do something similar for pins, but actually, you should explain what the root problem is here, rather than attacking some small part of it. It will get you better answers. See also [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Seriously consider normalising  your schema design

Comment: We have a database called hardware that contains tables named by the i2c address that they represent. Some hardware returns FLOAT(adc converters) and some returns INT (gpio) and they all have different amount of pins, therefor i can't use a table design like the one @TangentiallyPerpendicular proposed.  I need help formulating something like a dynamic sql procedure or maybe a function, but it's way over my level

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about your condition but you can try [PREPARED STATEMENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html). Perhaps something like this:

```
SET @tbl = NULL;
SET @col = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT address INTO @tbl FROM switches WHERE address='0x68';
SELECT pin INTO @col FROM switches WHERE address='0x68';

SELECT @tbl, @col;

SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT ',@col,' FROM `',@tbl,'`;');

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

There are three variables `@tbl, @col` & `@sql` here and each are quite self-explanatory. The processes are:

1. Set all variables with `NULL` value: just in case that the variables has been used and still holds the last value being set.
2. Assigning variables with table & column value that need to be used in the final query.
3. Setting `@sql` variable with a generated query concatenated with the table and column variables.
4. Prepare, execute and deallocate the statement.

P/S: Those `SELECT @tbl, @col` and `SELECT @sql` query in between are just for checking for what has been set in the variables and not required in the final query structure.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2eae6a89c36588ecdfb9ab38d1e695b)